# jqGrid: Search with smaller set of searchoptions does not work

Tags: jqgrid

jQGrid version : 3.7.2
jquery version: 1.4.2

Issue: creating search dialog with a subset of operators:

```
var searchOptions = {
        caption: 'Filter...',
        multipleSearch:true,
        closeAfterSearch:true,
        closeAfterReset:true
    };
$('#list').jqGrid({
   colModel: [
        {
            name:'abc', sorttype:'int', sortable: true, search:true,   
            searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']}
        }
   ],
   pager: '#pager'
}).navGrid('#pager', {search: true, edit:false, add:false, del:false}, 
           null, null, null,  searchOptions);
```

When the search popup comes up, pick 'Not Equal' and input a number and click on 'Search' button. The grid rows do not reflect the search criteria! However, if you remove 'searchoptions' from colModel, it works fine.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem. Probably you have a bug in your example.

You can verify on [the demo example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdvancedSearch.htm) that "equal" and "not equal" operations work. In the example 12 rows will be added in the grid. If you will search for 'Inv No' equal to 4, one row will be displyed. If you will search for 'Inv No' not equal to 4, first page from **11** rows will be displyed (see on the right size of the pager). If you will search for 'Inv No' not equal to 44, first page from **12** rows will be displyed. So all work without any problem.

I verified the results with jQuery 1.4.2 and jqGrid 3.7.2, but I am not a friend of retro versions and I used in the final version of the demo jQuery 1.4.4 and jqGrid 3.8.2.

Comment: I modified your demo and changed the onready handler to do this the following, which matches what I'm trying to do: