# Limit search option to just equal and not equal in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

I want to limit the search option on my grid to just **equal and not equal**. I don't want other options such as ***(contains,does not contain, begins with, does not begin with, is in, is not in.....)*** to display. I have tried this code so far but it does not work. Any help?

```
}).navGrid("#pager", {
    search:true,
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false,
    searchtext:"Search",
    refreshtext:"Refresh",
    searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','ne']}       
});
```

Thanks Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid: Search with smaller set of searchoptions does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974368/jqgrid-search-with-smaller-set-of-searchoptions-does-not-work)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question that link points to. But after looking at that link, I actually got what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Specify sort options explicitly for your columns like this;

```
colModel: [
            { name: "patientDOB",index:'patientDOB',search:true, width: 90,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} },
            { name: "referralProvider",index:'referralProvider',search:true, width: 90,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} },
            { name: "referralReason",index:'referralReason',search:true, width: 120,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} },
            { name: "contactName",index:'contactName',search:true, width: 100,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']}},
            { name: "contactPhone",index:'contactPhone',search:true, width: 100,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']}},
            { name: "contactEmail",index:'contactEmail',search:true, width: 100,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} }
]
```